# How to complete the html form with a data in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an object in JS:

```
var myFormObject= {};
MyFormObject.Name1 = "asdasd";
MyFormObject.Name2 = "aaa21";
MyFormObject.Name3 = "sadasd";
MyFormObject.SomethingElse= 111;
```

And I have a form:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input name="Name1" type="text"/>
   <input name="Name2" type="text"/>
   <input name="Name3" type="text"/>
   <input name="SomethingElse" type="text"/>
</form>
```

I want to complete `myForm` with a data stored in `myFormObject`. Something like this:

```
  $("#myForm").Complete(myFormObject)
```

I know that I can make it by accessing each `input` in my form 'by-hands' and complete it with data in the `JS-object`, but is there more elegant way? This can be usefull when I have the form with 100 of inputs and the object is returned from the `server-side`

Thanks for any advance.

Comment: Have a look on the Autocomplete widget for jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Here is an example with multiple inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/dqN7F/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the asker is going for, though, Stefan. It sounds like Maris is attempting to automatically populate an HTML form upon receiving a JS object with the needed data, not necessarily use an autocomplete function. I could be wrong, though. Clarification?

Comment: @ChrisForrence I see, probably I misunderstood the question.

Comment: `ChrisForrence` is right. I want to populate the form with JS object. Sorry for my bad english, I cant find the `right-word`. )

Answer (score 1):

Using the current naming pattern that you're using, you can go through and set the value in a for-loop.

```
var nt = 100;
var n;
for(var i = 1; i < nt; i++) {
    n = "Name" + i;
    $('input[name="' + n + '"]').val(MyFormObject[n]);
}
```

For performance gains, however, you can modify your form to include an ID (it can even follow the Name1, Name2, etc. pattern), then modify the for-loop.

```
var nt = 100;
var n;
for(var i = 1; i < nt; i++) {
    n = "Name" + i;
    $('#' + n).val(MyFormObject[n]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but what if some fields of `myFormObject` is also objects. Is there any way to `map` JS-object to the form, and should I look to the  `MVVM` way?

Comment: For that, you would use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a code example right now but this is the way I would try.

You could write a loop like:

```
each input in #myForm:
    complete input with object[input.attr(name)]
```

Let me know if this helps you already, otherwise I would write some testcode later.

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI has a builtin widget for autocomplete, and it is working with multiple input fields, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/dqN7F/

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input class="tags" />
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input class="tags" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
     var availableTags = [
         "ActionScript",
         "and",
         "so",
         "on"];
     $(".tags").autocomplete({
         source: availableTags
     });
 });
```

For even more options (scrollable suggestions, ajax loading of suggestions etc.) have a look at the documentaion: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/